# Jasmine unit testing on transient property

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I have a controller class whose constructor returns a completely separate object, but whose instance is "attached" to one of its own properties via members of the object it returns, like this:

```
//the controller class
define('myControllerClass', 
    ['myOtherClass'], function (myOtherClass) {
    //constructor
    function myControllerClass() {
        var that = this;
        this.renderingModule = null;
        this.aProperty = false;

        return {
            action1: function() {
                that.aProperty = true;
                that.renderingModule = new myOtherClass({
                    controller: that
                });
            },
            action2: function() {
                that.renderingModule = new myOtherClass({
                    controller: that
                });
            }
        }
    };
    return myControllerClass;
});

define('myOtherClass', [], function () {
    function myOtherClass(params) {
        this.controller = params.controller;

        if(this.controller.aProperty) doSomething();
    }

    return myOtherClass;
});

define('myTest' ['myControllerClass'], function(myControllerClass){
    //the test
    describe('test my controller class', function() {
        beforeEach(function() {
            this.controller = new myControllerClass();
        });

        it('Should set aProperty to true on action 1', function(done) {
            this.controller.action1();

            expect(this.controller.aProperty).toBe(true); // does not work because this.controller is an object containing the 2 actions
        })
    });
})
```

So the rendering module can access properties from the controller, but from the test I don't have any means to do so without instantiating a separate redering module.
Are there any tricks in Jasmine that would allow me to test on the value of aProperty?

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand what you're doing here... when you call `new myControllerClass()` it returns a function, not an object. How can `this.controller` be an object in your test?

Comment: I'm sorry, I tried to port the original code ommitting the require.js calls, and it seem like it got messy. when you instantiate new myControllerClass, the constructor (the inner myControllerClass) is called. in the test, the value of this.controller will be the returned object with the two actions.

Comment: I've edited the code to reflect what happens on my implementation.